# Как сделать, чтобы на сайт могли заходить только США и Европа?

Tags: php

Как и возможно ли сделать ограничение на сайт, чтобы зайти на него смогли только США и страны Европы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно конечно. Определяйте страну по IP и отбрасывайте нежелательных посетителей. Тут на помощь придет какая-нибудь база соответствий IP-страна. Такими решениями пользуется, например Steam для определения страны пользователя. 100% точного результата не даст конечно. Можно воспользоваться [Sypex Geo](http://sypex.net/ru/products/geo/) - класс для PHP, работает шустро, BSD - лицензия.

Comment: Точно, спасибо